# Packaging a web application with SignalR in docker-compose

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Good afternoon, I have a problem with packaging a web application with SignalR in docker. When running in docker, only REST requests work, websockets do not work. When you run the project through Visual Studio or dotnet run, everything works.

**dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 83
EXPOSE 446
COPY ./publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.API.dll"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  myvoice_vote_API:
          image: service_api
          container_name: service_API
          ports: 
              - "83:83"
              - "446:446"
          environment: 
              - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:446;http://+:83
```

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? What does it do?